How to modify a filepath relative to the tested file in jest?
I have a test function that uses a file in the following path in my nestjs application:
/Users/username/Documents/projectname/src/assets/responses/message.hbs
This path is provided by a file service and is build from the application path, that is:
'application path'+'assets/responses/message.hbs'
However, my test module thinks the application path is the test file path, and when it calls the file service, the service returns the following path instead:
/Users/username/Documents/projectname/src/modules/session/assets/responses/message.hbs' where modules/session/ is the path of my test file relative to src/ folder.
Is there a way to make jest think that my current test path is not /Users/username/Documents/projectname/src/modules/session/ but /Users/username/Documents/projectname/src/?
Here is an example of how my test configuration looks like:
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { Service } from './service.service';
import { FileHelperService } from '../../shared/modules/file-helper.service';

describe('Service', () => {
    let service: Service;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                Service,
                FileHelperService,
            ],
        }).compile();
        service = module.get<Service>(Service);
    });

    it('should compile', () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();

    describe('function that uses message.hbs', () => {
        service.functionThatUsesFile();
    });
});


What did you try and what were you expecting?
I'm running a test in this folder: /Users/username/Documents/projectname/src/modules/session/, but I would like my testing module to think it is being run from the following folder: /Users/username/Documents/projectname/src/.
